# Error in routing when i deploy NodeJS to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, routes

I have a simple app that lets you buy a product, and when you finish buying it, it sends a POST to /checkout, but i checked the logs and when you buy the prodcut, it times out and nothing is send via the POST method

**2020-07-15T21:04:50.461202+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/checkout" host=young-scrubland-66529.herokuapp.com
request_id=65e949ab-6c66-490f-811a-48295d4dc796 fwd="181.31.246.247" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https**

here is a link to the app https://young-scrubland-66529.herokuapp.com/

If i test it locally, it works correctly, but when i deploy it to heroku and try getting the POST request it fails, here it goes my code

```
router.post('/checkout', async (req, res) => {
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.stripeEmail,
    source: req.body.stripeToken
})
const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
    amount: '3000',
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Curso Online de Marketing',
    customer: customer.id
})
console.log(charge.id)
// Finally show a succes view
res.render('partials/download')
})
```

This is where i load the routes

```
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const path = require('path')

let puerto = process.env.PORT || 3000

// Initialize express
const app = express()

// Setings
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir:path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir:path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname:'.hbs'
}))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')

// Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:false }))
app.use(express.json())

// Routes
app.use(require('./routes/index'))

// Static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// Start server

app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(`Escuchando Puerto ${puerto}`)
})
```

and the form:

```
<form action="/checkout" method="POST">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_51H4oXrIlt5QpTspqXyEHX73ESibmXp6tMi5DbdkM2ye8joTZEgKJsBzE1WXhqOxaR6Eopql9wMmWSewCv3edFekB00PoU5hJud" 
    data-amount="3000"
    data-name="Curso Marketing"
    data-description="Marketing Cursos Online"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
    </script>
    <script>
        document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none'
    </script>
    <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block"> Comprar </button>
</form>
```

you can try buying with this test credit card:
4242424242424242
date:any date post today
code: any code

Comment: Could use please show us the code for your `index.js` or `app.js` where you load your routes?

Comment: sure, just added them